# Are SMPS (inductor) current limits mostly thermal?

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply

I'm building a boost converter that needs to boost 200A for 1 second and then shut down. The vast majority of reading I've done on SMPS and various PSU topologies assumes an RMS current and high duty cycle. Are the majority of component limits (FET, Diode, Inductor) purely thermal and how are they likely to heat with current?

Comment: Inductors are sensitive to current. To much current and they saturate and become a piece of wire or the insulation burns or the core looses its magnetic properties. As for other devices, refer to the datasheet. You can most likely run a low duty cycle to avoid exceeding the thermal specs. How hot will they get? That’s a thermodynamic problem.

Comment: Thanks @Kartman perhaps my question is better worded as "Will an inductor saturate if I pulse current through it for a short period of time?" or "How quickly does an inductor saturate?"

Comment: _"How quickly does an inductor saturate?"_ Picoseconds, if not faster.

Answer (score 3):

As with all components, an inductor has several limits, and you have to stay within them all.

The inductor has a saturation current limit, above which the inductor value quickly drops, to possibly 1/10th or even 1/100th of its low current value. This is instantaneous, so you would use the same design current whether operating at 1% or 100% duty cycle.

The effect of exceeding the saturation current by even a tiny amount would result in greatly increased current in your switches, resulting in at best reduced efficiency, and at worst overheating or destruction of them. Note that some overcurrent controls, whether by timing the on pulse or sensing the current, rely on the inductor having at least some minimum value, so that the rate of current increase is controlled. Losing inductance due to saturation means that the rate of current rise becomes 10 or 100 times larger than expected.

The inductor also has a thermal limit, which you can safely exceed for short periods, as long as the peak temperature does not exceed what is safe for the core and the wire insulation.

Read the data sheet for your other components as well, to understand which limits are instantaneous, and which are a thermal average.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Neil's answer --

Note that some types don't saturate very aggressively at all: most powdered iron (toroid and composite / molded) types roll off gradually, with -20 to -50% inductance being typical at nominal-max output current.

Ferrite types saturate more sharply, though I doubt you'd ever see one with a 1/100 ratio, for energy storage purposes; that would however be typical of transformers, so it's a very real hazard if you've designed a forward converter incorrectly, say.

The ratio is determined by material and geometry.  Inductors use low-mu materials and/or wide air gaps, both of which act to reduce the zero-bias inductance, while increasing saturation current.  (The two are inversely related, but energy goes as current squared, so this increases the total energy storage at Isat.)  Low-mu materials tend to saturate gently by themselves, while airgaps spread out the field locally, making saturation more gradual.

But these facts are largely irrelevant outside of magnetic design -- check the datasheet for saturation curves, and operate as far down it as you like.  The inductor doesn't care, in and of itself; its only limit is thermal.

As for circuit behavior, depends on design.  A bad old voltage-mode design will happily drive right into saturation, increasing peak switching current, dissipation, and potentially causing failure.  A proper current-mode design, encountering saturation, will reduce output (less maximum power is available than intended?), and may become unstable (due to short pulse widths), but is less likely to fail from an issue like this.